# Functioning App crashing on installing on Android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My app ran/runs fine in an earlier version and without problems in the emulator and on my device. Now I have copied the project via usb to another pc after not having any issues and I made a debug-build and one normal build and tried to install it on my device. This is where the problems start. No matter what, the app-installer crashes when I try to install the .apk.
Things I tried in Android Studio:

1. Clean Project & Make project
2. Clear all caches & Make project

Things I tried on my Phone:

1. Unistalled the older App-Version

The package-installer keeps crashing on my device.
Any Ideas what I can try?

Comment: Try uninstalling the older version of the app if you already have it installed on your phone and then install the new one.

Comment: Did that already

Comment: Did you generate another signed APK on the second build?

Comment: Everytime i clicked "make project", I did another build, loaded it on my device and tried to install it

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "the app-installer crashes"?  Could you post crash logs as well?

Comment: he says `package-installer` that eror/crash, check your compileSdkVersion and your phone android version, try to restart your phone.. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Go to build.gradle (Module:app, under Gradle Script) and check properties under android, you will see minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion.

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yourapp_package"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Change the api level to match it to your device api (android OS installed).
Rebuid and test it to your device.

Comment: The issue was a png file that was too big

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i put in some pngs as app logo that made the app crash on installing. I made my own assets out of these pngs and now it works like a charm